# Modal pop up bootstrap, jquery, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a form with modal pop up from bootstrap.

When I push the "Registrar" button, the hidden form appears and works fine. However, when I complete the form and push the send button, the data is saved in my database but the form doesn't hide.

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Mis tareas</title>

    <link href="estilos/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="estilos/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="estilos/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="estilos/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_ui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-validation-1.11.1/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-validation-1.11.1/lib/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-validation-1.11.1/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainjavaScript.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="formulario" Title="Registrarse">
            <form action="include/registro.php" method="POST" id="formRegistro" name="formRegistro" role="form">
                <fieldset id="ocultos">
                    <input type="hidden" id="accion" name="accion" class="{required:true}"/>
                </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="datosUser">
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="nombres">Nombres</label>
                    <span class="Info"></span>
                    <input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombres" placeholder="Nombres" class="form-control" required autofocus>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" class="form-control " required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="nick">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="text" id="nick" name="nick" placeholder="Nombre Usuario" class="form-control " required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="pass">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>            
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" class="form-control " required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="rpass">Repetir contrase&ntilde;a</label>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="password" id="rpass" name="rpass" placeholder="Repetir contrase&ntilde;a" class="form-control " required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="email">Email</label>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-gorup">
                    <label  for="departamento">Departamento</label>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="text" id="departamento" name="departamento" placeholder="Departamento" class="form-control " required>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
                <button id="send" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Continuar</button>

                <fieldset id="ajaxLoader" class="ajaxLoader hidden">
                    <img src="images/default-loader.gif">
                    <span>Espere un momento...</span>
                </fieldset>     

            </form>
        </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="include/login.php" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Inciar sesi&oacute;n</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="nick" id="nick" required autofocus>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Entrar</button>

      </form>
         <div id="btnAddUser" class="center addUser">
            <button id="irNuevoUser" class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Registrarse</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The js file:

```
$(function(){
          //creación de ventana formulario
          $('#formulario').dialog({
              autoOpen:false,
              modal:true,
              width:500,
            height:'auto',
            resizable: false,
            close:function(){
                $('#formRegistro fieldset > span').removeClass('error').empty();
                $('#formRegistro input[type="text"]').val('');
                $('#formRegistro input[type="password"]').val('');
                $('#formRegistro input[type="email"]').val('');
                $('#formRegistro select > option').removeAttr('selected');
            }
        });

        // funcionalidad del botón que abre el formulario
        $('#irNuevoUser').on('click',function(){
            // Asignamos valor a la variable acción
            $('#accion').val('addUser');

            // Abrimos el Formulario
            $('#formulario').dialog({
                title:'Agregar Usuario',
                autoOpen:true
            });
        });

    // Validar Formulario
        $('#formRegistro').validate({
            submitHandler: function(){

                var str = $('#formRegistro').serialize();

                // alert(str);

                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $('#formRegistro').show();
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "include/registro.php",
                    data: str + "&id=" + Math.random(),
                    success: function(response){
                             $('#formRegistro .ajaxLoader').hide();
                        // Validar mensaje de error
                        if(response.respuesta == false){
                            alert(response.mensaje);
                        }
                        else{
                            // si es exitosa la operación
                            $('#formRegistro .ajaxLoader').dialog({autoOpen:false});
                        }

                        $('#formulario .ajaxLoader').dialog({autoOpen:false});

                    },
                   error:function(xhr, status, error){
                        //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                /*      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                             console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                        }*/
                });

                return false;

            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.prev("span").append());
            }
        });

  });
```

And the php file that processes the data and sends it to the database:

```
<?php
include ("funciones.php");
//if(verifyuser()){
    $nick           = $_POST['nick'];
    $pass           = $_POST['pass'];
    $rpass          = $_POST['rpass'];
    $nombres        = $_POST['nombres'];
    $apellidos      = $_POST ['apellidos'];
    $email          = $_POST['email'];
    $departamento   = $_POST['departamento'];
    $idPersona      = "";
    $reqlen = strlen($nick) * strlen($pass) * strlen($rpass);

    if($reqlen > 0) {
        if ($pass === $rpass) {
            $pass = md5($pass);
            $idRol = 2;
            $estadoUsuario = 1;
            //require (funciones.php"); 
            consultar("INSERT INTO persona (nombres, apellidos, email, departamento) 
                        VALUES  ('$nombres', '$apellidos', '$email', '$departamento')");
            $execute = consultar("SELECT nombres, idPersona FROM persona WHERE nombres='$nombres'");
            //$execute = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
            if ($row=mysql_fetch_array($execute)){
                $idPersona  =   $row["idPersona"];
            }
            consultar("INSERT INTO login (nick, pass, email, rol_idRol, estadoUsuario, persona_idPersona) 
                        VALUES ('$nick', '$pass', '$email', '$idRol', '$estadoUsuario', '$idPersona')") or die (mysql_error());

            //echo "Los datos han sido enviados correctamente, revise su correo para obtener el link de alta de usuario";
            header("Location: ../registrook.html");
        } else {
            echo "Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden, ingresar dos contraseñas iguales.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Para continuar debe llenar todos los campos requeridos.";
    }
//}else {
    //header ("Location: error.php");
    //}
?>
```

I'm using firebug to try to find the error.
This is the response when I push the "send" button:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  885
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Mon, 22 Sep 2014 23:20:36 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Server  Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
ver código fuente
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-ar,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  PHPSESSID=9g25h7ailr0mpjmnetcaupvbu3
Host    localhost
Referer http://localhost/www/final3/index.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ES">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>GTD-MASTER</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link href="estilos/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>GTD-MASTER</h1>
            <h1>Bienvenidos al sistema Get Things Done</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- end #header -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <h5>Su registro se realizo correctamente.</h5>
                <h4>Para completar el mismo revise su correo para obtener el link para activar su cuenta.</h4>
                <a href="index.html" target="_self"> <input type="button" name="boton" value="Volver" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #content -->
        <div id="footer">
        <p id="legal"></a></p>
        <p id="brand"></p>
        </div>
        <!-- end #footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to be working but it doesn't show the success page and it doesn't hide the modal box.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see a direct call to Bootstrap ' modal() method,  I'm assuming that's what the dialogue() method is.   You can use:

```
$('#myModalId').modal('toggle');
```

Or in your case,  try:

```
$('#myModalId').dialogue('toggle');
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your fast answer, I did what you said but the form still not disappear.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?